# Woocommerce Excluding Certain Category from Shop Page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Trying to exclude a single category from my WooCommerce's Shop Page

I was using this code but it would break my sites's attributes filter links:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_pre_get_posts_query' );

function custom_pre_get_posts_query( $q ) {

    if ( ! $q->is_main_query() ) return;
    if ( ! $q->is_post_type_archive() ) return;

    if ( ! is_admin() && is_shop() ) {

        $q->set( 'tax_query', array(array(
           'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
           'field' => 'slug',
           'terms' => array( 'samples' ), 
           'operator' => 'NOT IN'
        )));

     }

     remove_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_pre_get_posts_query' );

}
```

Comment: I believe the shop page *is* the main query and it's definitely a post type archive, so those will prevent it from working on the shop archive.

Comment: @CarlosDaniel … Meaning that you should have to remove `if ( ! $q->is_main_query() ) return;` and `if ( ! $q->is_post_type_archive() ) return;` … :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This solution excluded the category from Shop Page. But the problem is, the Category archive page for the excluded category says no products available.

I've E-Books category which I don't want to enlisted on Shop Page. I have created a separate menu item for E-Books, which is where I want to list all books from the E-Books category.

How to achieve this?

**Update**

I added `if (!$q->is_main_query() || !is_shop()) return;` to the action hook and it resolved my above mentioned problem. This line excludes the category only from Shop page, however all products are listed good when the excluded category is accessed directly from menu (category page).

```
function custom_pre_get_posts_query( $q ) {

if (!$q->is_main_query() || !is_shop()) return;

$tax_query = (array) $q->get( 'tax_query' );

$tax_query[] = array(
       'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
       'field' => 'slug',
       'terms' => array( 'ebooks' ),
       'operator' => 'NOT IN'
);


$q->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );

}
```

`add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'custom_pre_get_posts_query' );`

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `woocommerce_product_query` hook, which is pretty similar to `pre_get_posts` except it already has the appropriate conditional logic. There is also a `woocommerce_product_query_tax_query` filter, but I'm not sure if that is exists in WooCommerce 2.6 or if its new in 2.7 beta.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'custom_pre_get_posts_query' );

function custom_pre_get_posts_query( $q ) {

    $q->set( 'tax_query', array(array(
       'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
       'field' => 'slug',
       'terms' => array( 'samples' ), 
       'operator' => 'NOT IN'
    )));

}
```

**EDIT** filtering is done through the taxonomy query, and in the above example we're overriding the tax query completely. I can't test that this works right now (and arrays of arrays are tricky so I may have messed up), but the theory is that we need to merge the new constraint with the existing taxonomy query generated by WooCommerce.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'custom_pre_get_posts_query' );

function custom_pre_get_posts_query( $q ) {

    $tax_query = (array) $q->get( 'tax_query' );

    $tax_query[] = array(
           'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
           'field' => 'slug',
           'terms' => array( 'samples' ), 
           'operator' => 'NOT IN'
    );


    $q->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );

}
```

Comment: The solution works to exclude the category from the homepage but it doesn't allow for filtering which is what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Please see the edit. Note, if you have have the filter widget set up with "OR" relationship I think you'll find it impossible to have OR relationships between the widgets and still have an AND relationship with excluding samples. Well not impossible, but would probably require you writing a custom `posts_where` SQL statement instead of writing a taxonomy query.

Comment: thank you so much, the code works flawlessly, I'll let you know if I run into any errors. Also changed the filter widget from "OR" to "AND" relationship to prevent any errors. You're a life saver.